# Cancel resonation impedance of a speaker

Tags: impedance, speakers

In a speaker there is a resonance impedance. Now I am trying to cancel this out in order to create a flat impedance graph for all frequencies.

I know this can be done by using a parallel Zobel network.

The problem lies in the resonance impedance. I think this can be flattened using a RLC circuit parallel to the speaker. I would like to simulate this using Pspice but I cannot seem to find the right values for the resistance,capacitance and inductance.

1. Would this work?
2. How can I calculate these values for R,C and L?

Answer (score 1):

For an explanation of the flattening of the post-resonance increase in impedance, take a look [here](https://sound-au.com/lr-passive.htm) - for a slightly less easy-to-read explanation of how to flatten the resonance peak (and the post-resonance ramp), take a look [here](http://users.on.net/~isaacmcn/audio/impcomp/impcomp.htm).

BTW - I found both of these using [Uncle Google](http://www.google.com/) and I learned something in the process.